# Get text_frame height and width in python-pptx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

How do I get the position, width, and height of the `shape.text_frame` ? I tried looking in the xml and have found something like this for this [shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdMc0.jpg)

```
<a:bodyPr lIns="90000" rIns="90000" tIns="91440" bIns="91440" anchor="ctr">
     <a:noAutofit/>
</a:bodyPr>
```

which doesn't mention any of these except for the margin from bbox of text_frame, and the vertical align.

If not possible to extract from xml then how it is calculated in slides or libreoffice?

Answer (score 0):

The `Shape` object whose `TextFrame` it is has `height` and `width` properties.

Comment: Shape object's height and width are different from Textframe's height and width. You can cleary see in the image I attached, Grey bordered bbox height and width is different from blue bordered bbox.